# Game Theory, Two-finger Morra

Tags: probability, game-theory

> Consider a variant of two-finger morra where the winner is still determined
>   by the parity of the sum of the two numbers thrown (if it’s even, Alice wins money and if it’s odd, Bob wins
>   money), but the amount won or lost is the product of the two numbers.
>
> If Alice plays 1 finger with probability p and 2 fingers with
>   probability 1 − p, what’s the expected payoff she gets even if Bob
>   knows p and can chose his strategy based on this knowledge? How should
>   Alice choose p such that this payoff is maximized?

Here's what I have so far, (assuming P(A=1) = p),

I know that the expected payoff for Alice is at least:

```
min(p - 2(1-p), -2p + 4(1-p))
```

And the expected payoff for Bob is at least (assuming P(B=1) = p),

```
min(p - 2(1-p), -2p + 4(1-p))
```

Which means that the optimal strategy for Alice would be to play 1 finger with probability 2/3, and the same goes for Bob.

I know how to get the expected payoff using these probabilities, but I don't know how to get the expected payoff for Alice if Bob knows p and can choose his strategy based on this knowledge. And how does Alice choose p such that the payoff is maximized?

Answer (score 0):

You should not assume the chance Bob plays $1$ is the same as the chance that Alice plays $1$, so let Bob play $1$ with probability $q$.  Now when Alice plays $1$ her payoff is $2(1-q)-1q$ and when she plays $2$ her payoff is $2q-4(1-q)$.  Her equilibrium strategy is to play these in a ratio that makes her expected payoff independent of $q$.